# Hadwiger number of a graph: Question about the original article from 1943

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, ho.history-overview, translation

I am analyzing Hadwiger's original article (Hadwiger, Hugo (1943), "Uber eine Klassifikation der Streckenkomplexe", Vierteljschr. Naturforsch. Ges. Zurich, 88: 133–143) for my work related to the Hadwiger Conjecture in graph theory.

This article is in German, and Hadwiger's terminology from 1943 is very different from current graph theory terminology. For example, he says "Komplex" for what we now call a graph, and he says "Simplex S(n)" for what we now call the complete graph $K_n$ over $n$ vertices. Also, when he says "K(k)", now we would call this a graph with Hadwiger number $k$ (for him, K(k) is not the complete graph).

In this article, he defines what we now call the Hadwiger number ${\rm had}(A)=k$, the size of the largest complete graph $K_k$ that can be obtained by contracting edges of $A$ (where $A$ is an undirected graph).

His original definition is

> Ein Komplex A heisst ein K(k), wenn er sich auf einen S(k),
> aber nicht auf einen S(k+1) zusammenziehen lässt. Ein K(k) ist notwendig ein zusammenhängender Komplex.

I am translating this into current terminology *"An undirected graph $A$ has Hadwiger number $k$, if the complete graph $K_k$, but not $K_{k+1}$, can be obtained by contracting edges of $A$. It is necessarily a connected graph."*

In the next sentences he says

> Die Eigenschaft, ein K(k) zu sein, kennzeichnet eine Art des höheren Zusammenhangs, die durch die natürliche Zahl k gegeben ist.

What does "höheren Zusammenhangs" mean here? My current terminology translation would be *"The property to have Hadwiger number $k$ characterizes a higher degree of connectedness, which is given by the natural number $k$"*.

But my second, more deliberate translation sounds more logical to me: *"The property to have Hadwiger number $k$ characterizes a more abstract idea of connectedness, which can just be expressed by the natural number $k$"*. But it is more of an interpretation than the first version.

I have asked two German native speaker scientists, but they were not sure as they are no experts in graph theory. It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: If that helps: In algebraic topology one would say the same about vanishing of homotopy groups up to degree k: Das Verschwinden der Homotopiegruppen bis zur Ordnung k charakterisiert eine höhere Art des Zusammenhangs charakterisiert eine Art des höheren Zusammenhangs.

Comment: The meaning of „höher“ is as in „in einem höheren Sinn“, which (I think) translates into English as „in a higher sense“.

Comment: @ThiKu great comment. It is true that Zusammenhang might not refer to connectedness here. Let me give it a thought or two, it is interesting.

Comment: Actually I meant that Zusammenhang would mean connectedness but that höherer Zusammenhang might mean „connectedness in a higher sense“ as well as a ‚numerically higher‘ connectedness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me give it a try. As a disclaimer, English is not my mother tongue, so my translation might have linguistic flaws.

First of all, I would say the sentence is hard to translate and it is a bit informal, i.e. it is not a rigorous mathematical statement. In my view, this sentence  gives an informal motivation why it it is useful to look a "K(k)" graphs, i.e. graphs with Hadwiger number $k$. Secondly, I think your 2nd version is relatively close to what this sentence means, but I think the meaning goes *beyond* connectedness.

My suggestion is to translate it in the context of the beginning of the whole paragraph where you took the quotes from. The first sentence in this paragraph reads:

"Im folgenden sprechen wir von einer Möglichkeit der Klassifikation der
Streckenkomplexe, die besonders im Hinblick auf das Problem der chromatischen Zahl von besonderem Interesse zu sein scheint."
(My translation: *In the following, we speak of a possible classification of graphs, which seems to be of particular interest regarding the problem of chromatic number.*)

So this is setting the scene really broadly, and announcing that the following definition could be relevant for the chromatic number problem, and in particular for the famous 4-color-problem.
Next, he defines the Hadwiger number (his "K(k)" graphs), and then there is the sentence you are asking about. Here is my suggested translation:

> The property of having Hadwiger number $k$ ($k$ a natural number) characterizes a deeper connection between those graphs. *(in the sense of: deeper than the ordinary notion of connectendness)*

Comment: I don‘t think that it is a statement about connections between the graphs. It is a statement about one graph for the moment.

Comment: @ThiKu I would tend to think "connection between these graphs" is actually ok. Grammatically, Hadwiger refers to one object, but what he really refers to is one property that all these graphs (with Hadwiger parameter k) have in common. I think, his term "ein K(k)" is representing a whole class of graphs, the defining property of this class.